# how to pass data between screen when using functional style component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have a functional component like below

```
const Screen1 = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
...
...
<Button
   onPress={() => {
   sqlite_wrapper.createtable(sqlite_wrapper.collection_product)
   navigation.navigate('Screen2');
        }}
/> 
...
...
  )
```

If it was a class component I can use `this` as below

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
     yourArray: this.state.yourArray, });
   }
```

Since I'm using purely functional component how to send and access data between screens.

Comment: Using navigation to pass around data is in my opinion a code smell. There either should be a "global app state" (either through Context, Redux, MobX etc), or every screen should be responsible for fetching it's own data.

Comment: @nbokmans I didn't understand what you are trying to say !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can pass params like usual as an object in navigation.navigate method even if you are using a functional component.

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => {
          /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
          });
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Link to official docs where they explain it: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params